# How do I update ODOO with changes I made to .po file when running from code

Tags: eclipse, postgresql, internationalization, odoo

I'm running ODOO from Eclipse (on Windows).

I changed a translation string (the module name) and now want to see it updated in odoo running from my (source code). I stopped and restarted the ODOO server in eclipse, and don't see the difference (it's still in English). Has the string been loaded somewhere to the database?

What do I need to do, to see the updated change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either update the module, which holds the translation you've changed or just reload the whole translation for the language you've changed something for.

The last is handled under Settings/Translations.

Comment: Will be checking this on Sunday. If ok, I'll mark it as the correct answer.